# How to make a certain function repeat forever

Tags: discord.py

So i'm trying to make like a mps system (money per second) and here's what i got:

```
class Test(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self,client):
        self.client = client
        self.money.start()
```

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=1)
    async def money(self):
      users = await self.get_bank_data()
      for id in ids:  
        money = users[str(id)]["wallet"]
        cps = 1
        money += cps
        await self.update_bank(id, money ,"wallet")
```

But it seems to get stuck on `for id in ids:` but I ran a `@client.event` and it prints the id fine.

**@client.event**

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Ready!")
    for cog in cogs:
        print(cog,"working")
        client.load_extension(cog)
    for id in ids:
      print(id)
    return
```

Output: `my id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way i can think of is using discord.ext.tasks

first implement a global variable to hold the user ids you want to update. Do this as you please, set them in a database or whatever.

Then

```py
from discord.ext import tasks

@tasks.loop(seconds=1)
async def money(self):
    for user_id in list_of_users:  # define this somewhere
        monei = users[str(user_id)]["wallet"]
        cps = 1
        monei += cps
        await self.update_bank(user_id, monei ,"wallet")  # update this function to use user_id or use bot.get_user or guild.get_member to retreive the appropiate object.
```

Using tasks.loop is the easiest way to set up a repetitive function. Beware that loops do not have context.

Here's the appropiate docs:
[tasks.loop](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=tasks#discord.ext.tasks.loop)

Comment: 2 problems, one: when I run I did a print() to see if it does loop, it doesn't, and two: not sure how to define user_id and list_of_users. If you have discord feel free to contact me. Note I followed how the docs did it and im not sure if im missing something

Comment: Are you starting the loop? You need to do `self.money.start()` probably in your cog `__init__`.